# React useState with object update several states in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, web, use-state

How can I change only a few states in an object useState?
For example:

```
const [team, setTeam] = useState({
manager: "",
captain: "",
goalkeeper: "",
defender: "" })
```

Now I only want to update the value manager and goalkeeper at the same time. How is that possible?

I tried:

```
setTeam({ ...team, manager: newValue });
setTeam({ ...team, captain: newValue2 });
```

But it updates only one of those.

I also tried:

```
 setTeam({ ...team, manager: newValue, captain: newValue2 });
```

It didn't work.

It is possible to change only a certain amount of variables in an useState object?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you please show complete code because your code looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does
> not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:

To achieve the behaviour you expect, you need to do the following:

```
setTeam(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, manager: newValue, captain: newValue2 };
});
```

You may also want to consider using useReducer as your state has multiple sub values, useState is usually best used with single value states.

You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTeam(currentState => ({
  ...currentState,
  manager: 'Thom',
  goalkeeper: 'Jan'
}))
```